# limit of $x!/x^4$, as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

It's $\infty/\infty$, so the next step would be to use the L'hospital rule. But the derivative of $n!$ is ... strange.

Is there another way to prove that the limit does not exist?

Comment: Graph it! ${} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer would be observing the ratio between each term.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)!/(x+1)^4}{x!/x^4} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)!}{x!} \frac{x^4}{(x+1)^4}$$

The first term is $x$, and the second term tends to $1$. The product therefore tends to $x$, which in turn tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Actually I was just trying to use the root test on the series $ n!^n/n^4n $, so this does help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could prove that there is no limit if for any $y$ you could find an $x$ such that $x! / x^4$ exceeds $y$. Can you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $n-1\le x<n$:

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n^4}
\le
\frac{x!}{x^4}
\le
\frac{n!}{(n-1)^4}
$$
and as ${n^4}/{(n-1)^4}\to 1$, we can prove the result only for $x=n\in\Bbb N$.

We can find an $N$ such as for $n>N$,
$$
\frac{n^5}{(n-1)^5}<n
$$
then if 
$$
n^5\le C n!,\\
(n+1)^5 \le (n+1)Cn! = C(n+1)!
$$

Now take 
$
C = \sup\{ n^5/ n!, n\le N
\}
$.
We immediately have
$$
n^5\le C n!
$$when $n\le N$ as well as when $n>N$ via induction.

Eventually,
$$
\frac{n^4}{n!} = \frac 1n \frac{n^5}{n!}\le \frac Cn\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x!}{x^4}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdot (x-4)!}{x^4}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\dfrac1x\right)\left(1-\dfrac2x\right)\left(1-\dfrac3x\right)\cdot (x-4)!=\cdots$$